# [React]different ways of fetching asynchronous data into component

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm a bit new to React world and get confused recently when I start writing Ajax stuff inside components.

As far as I can see, here are 2 ways of rendering **asynchronous** data into a Component as following:

1st way:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component
{
    render() {
      this.props.userList.map((userInfo) => (<span>{userInfo.name}</span>));
      // proceed to render userList
    }
}

//userAjaxSelect is a customized selector based on the Reselect lib
//ajax operation happens here!!
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
      userList:userAjaxSelect(state, props)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = null;// mapDispatchToProps is omitted here

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

2nd way:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component
{

  componentDidMount() {
    //FetchUserList is a redux ActionCreator and omitted here
    //it dispatches redux action
    //To get ajax response and sync to local UI state.
    this.setState({userList: FetchUserList(this.props.groupId)})
  }  

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if(nextProps != this.props)
      //FetchUserList is a redux ActionCreator and omitted here
      //it dispatches redux action
      //To get ajax response and sync to local UI state.
      this.setState({userList: FetchUserList(nextProps.groupId)})
    }

    render() {
      this.state.userList.map((userInfo) => (<span>{userInfo.name}</span>);
      // proceed to render userList
    }
}
```

From my point of view,

1st solution:

The ajax operation is encapsulated in a Selector which is used in  Reselect lib and I think it is pretty clean and can benefit the component performance (by cache)

2nd solution:

Is it a bad one ? because many times I've been warned by a few articles that the componentWillReceiveProps is discouraged to set States (**Anti-pattern**)? and moreover the way it implements is relatively  verbose

---

Which one is best practice or any other better alternatives? when it comes to loading and refreshing Ajax data

Answer (score 2):

I honestly never used any of the approaches you showed. As per documentation you might wanna have any AJAX request in `componentDidMount` and avoid doing AJAX in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

The reason behind it is that your component should be mounted even without the necessary data, you don't want to block the view (as it would happen if you used `componentWillMount` for example) if the request takes too long. The pattern that I see frequently is the following:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isFetching: false, userList: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isFetching: true });
    // In this case FetchUserList is just a simple AJAX call
    // not an action
    FetchUserList(this.props.groupId)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ userList: data, isFetching: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    this.state.userList.map((userInfo) => (<span>{userInfo.name}</span>);
  }
}
```

This does not take into account error handling but I hope you get the picture (you can use `.catch` for it). You can even prevent sending the request if your state is already populated, or avoid setting the state if the data is already there and so on...

On the other hand if you are using `redux` there are many middlewares that help with that like `redux-thunk`, alternatively I did create a middleware as well called `redux-slim-async` that reduces boilerplate and is a combination of what showed in the redux docs and some additional features. At the end of the day use what you are comfortable with and what makes more sense for your code base.

---

A different approach that makes use of `redux` could be to just fire the async action inside `componentDidMount`, then your component listens to the portion of the state (with `mapStateToProps`) that it's interested in and with `componentWillReceiveProps` you can update the inner state of the component based on new props received from your manager. What you showed was kind of a hybrid that I would not recommend.

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { userList: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // In this case FetchUserList is an Action
    FetchUserList(this.props.groupId)
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if(nextProps != this.props) {
       this.setState({ userList: nextProps.propFromStateManager });
     }
  }

  render() {
    this.state.userList.map((userInfo) => (<span>{userInfo.name}</span>);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that `componentWillReceiveProps` should be used only if you need to update the inner state of the component based on some `props` change. The scenario  where I would see `reselect` come in handy is when you want to send the `fetch` request anyway update the state and then `reselect` will check for you if the state is exactly the same, in that case it might prevent a re-render. Otherwise I wouldn't fire an ajax request from selector. If I were to jump in your code I would never expect to fins an async call in a selector, that's not what they are for.

Let me know if you need clarification and I will update the answer.

Comment: I'm aware of a few middlewares like React-thunk,React-saga ,etc. However middlewares function in dispatch&Action level which are not my concerns.     Actually my project decides to use Reselect library to speed up the redux , so I wonder if it is common pattern to put ajax in a Selector(used in mapStateToProps)when we need to integrate react-redux with Reselect?

Comment: I updated the answer, reselect makes sense if you need to fire the same request even though you already have the data, in this case reselect will leverage memoization and avoid firing a re render. But I would avoid sending the request in the first place if I already have the data.

Comment: As per doc, Reselect takes a number of parameters (.e.g. the sliced state ,component and ownProps) and if any of these are mutated , the result of that selector will be recalculated and synchrozied to mapStateToProps ,which I think exactly serves the same purpose as your solution which updates UI state in componentWillReceiveProps in response to any new props. What's more Updating component state in  componentWillReceiveProps looks rather verbose and redundant.          All above might be straightforward and might not make sense , please correct me if I'm wrong , thanks!!

Comment: With the mapStateToProps, this.props(used for output in render) can be updated automatically in response to any new props and new mutation of interested states,so why would we do that in componentWillReceiveProps while having more codes?  please share your point , thanks!thanks!