# Two simultaneous calls to one function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function in my react project, that returns choices after fetching them from API, if they were not already present. Something like this:

```
changeSubCategory = id => {
    // do something
    const { category } = this.props;
    subCategory = category[id];
    if (!subCategory.choices) {    // checking if there is choices key in subCategory or not (this is returning 'true' for both calls)
        categoryService.fetchChoices(subCategory.id).then(data => {    // call API to fetch 'choices' data
            subCategory.choices = data;    // set choices in subCategory
        });
    }
    this.setState({ category, subCategory });
    return subcategory;
}
```

This function is called 2 times simultaneously, one from a function, another from ComponentWillReceiveProps, which ends up making 2 api calls (because `subCategory.choices` is found empty in both cases.

I have tried following things from some similar questions on this site:

1. This function is using `.then()`, but still not working for me.
2. Tried using `async/await`, (looks like my component is rendering without choices in this case).
3. The rules in my project do not allow me to use `timeout` in this.

Note: This function is called from 3 places (2 places I mentioned above, third one from componentDidMount). So during mounting, it is called 3 times.

Is there anything else that can help me assign the variable `choices`, and preventing second api call?

Comment: This is going to impact also the places in your code where you *call* `subcategory`, since it cannot return the result synchronously. So probably best that you add the code where it is called.

Comment: I have only some experience of React programming, but I think you might be initiating several simultaneous fetches before getting results even from the first one. You should update the "component state"  before beginning the fetch so that you know to start the fetch only once. Like this:
if(!this.state.isFetching) { this.state.isFetching = true; categoryService.fetchChoices....

Comment: I tried this method already. I was setting isFetching=true before fetching and false after getting result. This help me reduce the 2 api calls to 1, but during mount it still calls api 2 times (3 before this implementation). I want to make it 1 call.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325389/reactdifferent-ways-of-fetching-asynchronous-data-into-component/48326147#48326147

Answer (score 0):

What @loop said in Comments.

Also, you're calling `this.setState({ category, subCategory });` synchronously, but it should be in the promise handler, after `subCategory.choices = data;`. This may not be an issue now, because the last call to `this.setState` might be after the first `subCategory.choices = data;`, but if you do what @loop said then I think you'll need to move the `this.setState` part.